# g3log no output until shutdown under linux, works under windows10

Tags: linux, logging

While running an app i'm working on, I noticed that under linux (ubuntu 22 & 23) there was no g3 log output until the app shutdown, while the same app logs properly under windows 10. Boiled it down to a test program which demonstrates the issue on 3 different linux boxes.
Here is how I'm building g3log:

```
git clone https://github.com/KjellKod/g3log.git
cd g3log
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release  -DENABLE_FATAL_SIGNALHANDLING=OFF -DUSE_DYNAMIC_LOGGING_LEVELS=ON -DG3_SHARED_LIB:BOOL=ON ..
make install
```

and the test program:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

#include "g3log/g3log.hpp"
#include "g3log/logworker.hpp"


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // initialize g3log 
    auto logger = g3::LogWorker::createLogWorker();
    auto handle = logger->addDefaultLogger("test_g3log", ".");
    g3::initializeLogging(logger.get());
    handle->call(&g3::FileSink::overrideLogDetails, &g3::LogMessage::FullLogDetailsToString);

    std::future<std::string> log_file_name = handle->call(&g3::FileSink::fileName);
    std::cout << "log file at: [" << log_file_name.get() << "]" << std::endl;

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        LOG(INFO) << "test";
    }

}
```

build:  `g++ -o main.exe main.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lg3log`

Runs fine under Windows 10, but no output under ubuntu 22 until program shuts down. I must be missing something simple...

Answer (score 0):

from source code, it turns out that the log is flushed every 100 entries by default. in both app and my test code, not enough output to flush. This can be addressed by calling addSink() rather than addDefaultLogger(), and overriding the default flush interval via the final parameter in addSink() :

```cpp
// flush output every log message instead of default 
auto handle = logger->addSink(std::make_unique<g3::FileSink>(kDefaultLogName, kDefaultLogPath, "g3log", 1), &g3::FileSink::fileWrite);
```

I'm don't know why i saw output under Windows prior to shutdown when calling addDefaultLogger().

It would be helpful if this were mentioned more prominently in the documentation.